# How to add Permissions to Lambda Function while using Amplify CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Is there any way to edit the lambda function in the AWS console and have it reflect in my local project?

When I do this and follow up by `amplify pull` to bring the changes over, the amplify cli says there are no changes made in the function and going through with it doesnt edit my function locally.

I was able to edit the lambda locally to a certain degree: adding layer, environment variable etc using `amplify update function`. But I want to be able to add permissions (preferably in the console and bring it over to local) as well as add VPC connection and edit.

There is an option under `amplify update function` called resource based permission but its not what I am looking for. I want the flexibility the console offers.

How can I do all these in the Amplify CLI??

Help & thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the fastest way to get your template file but this is how I find it:

If you go to your lambda in the console, and select its corresponding Application, go to the Deployments tab and in the SAM template section you will see a button to take you to the CloudFormation stack. From there select the Template tab and you can see the template in JSON format.  You can also select View in Designer and toggle between JSON and YAML.

You might be able to copy that into your local version and that should sync them up depending on what template format you are using.